# Solr edismax - exact match versus fuzzy

Tags: solr, solr4

- Doc 1: product_name:widget, model_number:abc123
- Doc 2: product_name:widget, model_number:def456
- Doc 3: product_name:widget, model_number:ghi789

Assume we are using edismax and our user makes a mistake entering their model number and types *widget abc12x* into the search box. We match all three documents on product_name but none on model_number, even though we have a close match for document 1.

What is the best way to handle this situation so we can make the user aware their model_number was not an exact match but that Doc 1 is probably what they were looking for? Fuzzy search (abc12x~) obviously will deal with this elegantly but we don't know ahead of time that it will be required, nor do we want to use it willy-nilly only to end up hurting search relevance,  performance etc.

Probably a basic question but new to Solr. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your index will get a lot bigger, but N-grams are a good way to get partial matches. For your scenario an [edge N-gram](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory) would work.

Answer (score 0):

You can add character proximity modifiers to the terms to handle this at query time:

```
q={!edismax}widget~3 abc12x~3
```

This will find terms in the index within ['edit distance'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance) of the provided search terms. This has the benefit of also matching the query term 'acb123' to the index term 'abc123'. Inserting or deleting a character are each one edit, swapping two characters is two edits.